# statsmodel logistic regression prediction function with dimension issue

Tags: python, logistic-regression, prediction

I built my model with training data X_train (21 columns) and y_train as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
statsmodels_result=logit_model.fit()
print(statsmodels_result.summary2())
statsmodels_predictions = statsmodels_result.predict(X_test)
statsmodels_predictions
```

I got the following errors:
ValueError: shapes (305772,21) and (22,) not aligned: 21 (dim 1) != 22 (dim 0)

I checked the shape of both X_train and X_test as follows:

```
print(np.asarray(X_train).shape)
print(np.asarray(X_test).shape)
```

```
(715203, 21)
(305772, 21)
```

I did the above analyses successfully with sk_learn with the same data set.

Could you please help me anything I did wrong?

Comment: can you post a sample of your data for testing purposes.  Ols should work fine with time series data.

Comment: maybe you added a constant column to X_train but not to X_test. It looks like your estimated parameter has length 22 and not 21

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing using an lstm network. lstm is very good for timeseries problems

```
lag=4

train, test = data[0:train_size, :], data[train_size:train_size + test_size, :]
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, lag)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, lag)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, lag)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)

trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

 # invert predictions
 trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
 trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
 testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
 testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
 # calculate root mean squared error
 trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:, 0]))
 print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
 testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:, 0]))
 print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
 # shift train predictions for plotting
 trainPredictPlot = np.empty_like(data)
 trainPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
 trainPredictPlot[lag:len(trainPredict) + lag, :] = trainPredict
 # shift test predictions for plotting
 testPredictPlot = np.empty_like(data)
 testPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
 testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict) + (lag * 2) + 1:len(data) - 1, :] = testPredict
 # plot baseline and predictions
 plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(data))
 plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
 plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
 plt.show()
```